# What does "step size" actually do in DeepDream?

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network, deep-dream

What does "step size" actually do in DeepDream?

It seems like the number of octaves, and the octave scales are basically resizing the image in certain patterns, while the iteration count is building on the hallucinated details. But what is the "step" or "step size" value doing during the DeepDream process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step size in DeepDream is just the learning rate.